# Why does the volumetric flow rate increase downstream for a jet?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I did a laboratory and the volumetric flow rate increased downstream and I don't understand why? Are there any sources that say why this is? I tried searching and I don't understand

The apparatus was the following https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICqtL.png

It was measured with a pitot static tube connected to a manometer and velocity was found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a property called entrainment, in which the central high speed jet shares its kinetic energy with parcels of fluid at the margins of the jet, setting them in motion, which then share with other parcels farther off-axis to set them in motion, and so on. Downstream from the origin of the jet you then observe that it has spread itself out and now consists of a larger volume of air which is traveling slightly slower.